# Java - Is there a Sink in Java

Tags: java, null

This is a question that came to my mind when I was writing a simple custom Log4j implementation (Java).

I wanted to make a custom Log4j Appender, which was done by extending the AppenderSkeleton Class. I have chosen to write the logging messages to a List (*Basically append method will add the message to the List*). I also want to have a close option. Since this is a simple implementation, I thought that close method can replace the List reference with a **Sink / Null Reference**, so that all the messages are just lost like that.

Then the question came to my mind. Is there actually a **Sink** that can be used **in Java**?

What I'm expecting is something equivalent to **/dev/null** in Linux, but in Application Programming Level.

Comment: Also is there a method to reference the equivalent **/dev/null** in OS, from Java _(Mainly Windows and Linux)_.

Comment: It's just a few lines to write a sub class of `OutputStream` that ignores everything you write. There is no such thing in the standard library.

Comment: @Balu If you just want to discard the list, do so *(set list field to null)*. Why waste time writing it to nowhere?

Comment: @Henry [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) has a [`NullWriter`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullWriter.html) and a [`NullOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/NullOutputStream.html). But yeah, it's easy enough to write your own.

Comment: @Andreas Setting the list to null will throw NullPointerException. However NullWriter / NullOutputStream works well. This also gave me an idea to implement a custom output stream or writer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Henry Apache Commons IO has a NullWriter and a NullOutputStream. But yeah, it's easy enough to write your own. – Andreas